# Replace outliers of a dataframe with the mean value

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, outliers

I want to find all the outliers in a dataframe and replace them by the mean of the variable (column).

This is a big dataframe, composed of 46 obs. of 147 variables.

I was thinking of doing somethings like

```
new_df <- for (i in scaled.df){
  i[!i %in% boxplot.stats(i)$out]
```

And then replace NULL values, but that function creates a NULL object, I believe the reason is that the new vectors created won´t have the same length.

Any ideas? Thx

Comment: beware: changing the value of outliers might change the properties of your data (and thus also of the mean/median/sd/etc..)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function to do this -

```
replace_outlier_with_mean <- function(x) {
  replace(x, x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out, mean(x))  
}
```

To apply for multiple columns you can use `lapply` -

```
scaled.df[] <- lapply(scaled.df, replace_outlier_with_mean)
```

Or in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
scaled.df %>% mutate(across(.fns = replace_outlier_with_mean))
```